# Not able to do get request using global variable in Node js and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

this is a small code from my index.js file in backend:

```
var topic = "";

app.post(`/posts`,(req,res)=>{
    topic = req.body.ReadMore;
    res.redirect(`/posts/${topic}`);
});

app.get(`/posts/${topic}`, (req,res) => {
    res.render('page')
})
```

I am trying to change the value of variable `topic` and then I want to redirect to `/posts/topic` . However, I am getting this error : `Cannot GET /posts/topicName` (console is showing error 404). Why is this not working? Also if I just hard code the topicName to my get request
, for example,

```
 app.get('/posts/topicName', (req,res) => {
    res.render('page')
})
```

It works perfectly. But in my case, I have many topics which can be passed to the server and I need to render pages relevantly.

Comment: `app.get('/posts/:topic')` is what you're looking for, What you're doing here is `app.get('/posts/')`

Comment: The first code is not going to work, as when the `get` handler was added, the template string is only evaluated once, and at that time `topic` is just empty string, so what you actually did is just like `app.get('/posts/', ...)`.
You can use `/posts/:topic` for second handler, then use `req.params.topic` to access the topic (no global variables necessary here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/posts/${topic}` is evaluated once. So if `topic` is an empty string, the middleware sees the value of the path as `/posts/`. Even if you change the value of the `topic` variable, the path is already set.

You can use this `/post/:topic` to have topic as a dynamic parameter for express. You can then use

```
const topic = "";
app.get(`/posts/:topic`, (req,res,next) => {
    const param_topic = req.params.topic;
    if (param_topic == topic) {
         // do something
    }
    else 
    {
         return next()
    }
   )}
```